# how to find all string containing http but not www javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, regex-negation

Tried negative look ahead but that doesnt seem to help

```
/^(?!www).(https:\/\/[^\s$\<]+)/g)
```

---

```js
const regex = /(?!www).(https:\/\/[^\s$\<]+)/g;

[
  'https://google.fr',
  'https://www.google.fr',
  'www.google.fr',
  'google.fr',
].forEach((x) => {
  console.log(regex.test(x));
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use this since it's for validating links also :

```js
const regex = /https?:\/\/(?!www\.)[-a-zA-Z0-9@:%._\+~#=]{1,256}\.[a-zA-Z0-9()]{1,6}\b([-a-zA-Z0-9()@:%_\+.~#?&//=]*)/;
    
[
  'https://google.fr',
  'https://www.google.fr',
  'www.google.fr',
  'google.fr',
].forEach((x) => {
  console.log(regex.test(x));
});
```